# Firebase Message not on iOS - FIRMessaging received data-message, but FIRMessagingDelegate's-messaging:didReceiveMessage: not implemented

Tags: ios, firebase, ionic3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am working on an ionic app and I have integrated firebase push notifications. On android everything works fine, but on iOS I'm getting below error in the log. I have enabled push notifications capabilities on XCode as well. Any idea why am I getting this error?

```
FIRMessaging received data-message, but FIRMessagingDelegate's-messaging:didReceiveMessage: not implemented
```

Answer (score 0):

I got it fixed.
I am using below method to get the token.

```
// Get permission from the user
async getToken() {

    return await new Promise(async (resolve) => {
        let token: String;

        if (this.platform.is('android')) {
            token = await this.firebaseNative.getToken();
            console.log('Android device instance id : ', token);
            resolve(token);
        }

        if (this.platform.is('ios')) {
            token = await this.firebaseNative.getToken();
            await this.firebaseNative.grantPermission();
            console.log('iOS device instance id : ', token);
            resolve(token);
        }
    });
}
```

the issue was with this code line.

```
await this.firebaseNative.grantPermission();
```

once it's removed it worked.